# Is there a symbol for the antidiagonal matrix that has 1 as every entry?

Tags: matrices, notation

Is there a symbol for the antidiagonal matrix that has 1 as every entry? For example, in two dimensions 
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Why you need a symbol, it's just antidiagonal matrix. I don't know any symbols though, and apart from identity matrix , most of the matrix don't have symbols.

Comment: Just take $I$, the symbol for the identity matrix, and rotate it through a right angle.

Comment: There is a multitude of reasons: 1. To make my working more readable. 2. To make it easier to refer to. 3. For use in mnemonics. I see you also had trouble referring to it as ``it's just antidiagonal matrix'' is ambiguous and doesn't make sense grammatically.

Comment: @JosephDewdney The symbol is $J_n$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix

Comment: @calculus Thank you. If you change your comment to an answer I'll be able to mark it as my accepted answer.

Comment: This $J_n$ is not a standard notation. Choose anything you deem fit, and give a proper definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A  row reversed identity matrix ($I_n$) can be denoted as $$J_n=\left( \begin{array}{} 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{array} \right)$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) for further infomation.

$J_n$ is also used to notate an all-ones matrix (see comment). On the other hand the all-ones matrix is often notated as $\textbf 1_n$. To avoid any confusion you have to define notations.

Comment: But I've seen $J$ used to denote the all-ones matrix.

Comment: After I browsed the Internet I have seen that $J_n$ is also used to notate all-ones matrix. So your objection is absolute right. Thanks for theat I use $\textbf 1_n$ to notate an all-ones matrix.

Comment: And $J$ is often used for Jordan blocks as well: in a work where the Jordan reduction is used, it would be advisable to chose another notation for the exchange matrix.